# Set view controllers property before pushViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

In my app I've added a label to a view, connected it to an outlet but nothing shows up when I first assign this outlet from another view controller and then call `pushViewController` to display it. Here's the code before pushing next view that display the label:

```
CustomViewController *vc = [[CustomViewController alloc] init];
vc.lbl_price.text = self.label_price.text; // lbl_price is defined as a property in CustomViewController and label_price is defined in current view controller
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc];
```

In the `CustomViewController` `viewDidLoad` method I added this instruction to see if it should work

```
NSLog(@"Price=%@",lbl_price); // it actually prints out what was previously assigned
```

But it doesn't show into the label!

Any idea why ?

Stephane

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Even if view controller is created its view hierarchy may not (and so all subviews will still be nil), for optimization reasons it may not be loaded until you try to actually access controller's view. You have two options to solve your problem:

1. Store all values in separate non-UI variables and assign them to UI components with controller is going to appear:

   ```
   // Before push controller
   vc.myPriceText = self.label_price.text;

   // In controller's viewWillAppear:
   self.lbl_price.text = self.myPriceText;
   ```
2. Make [vc view] call to force controller to load its view hierarchy:

   ```
    CustomViewController *vc = [[CustomViewController alloc] init];
    [vc view];
    vc.lbl_price.text = self.label_price.text; 
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc];
   ```