# Cannot set image property of UIImageView

Tags: ios

So, i have a .xib file which basically just contains a view, and within that, a scrollview with a UIImageView and a UIITextView. I have outlets connected to these subviews.

For some reason, i cannot set the image property of the image view. Below is how i instantiate the view controller in my UITableview:

```
 MyNewViewController *ssv = [[MyNewViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"MyNewViewController" bundle:nil];
[[self navigationController]pushViewController:ssv animated:YES];
ScreenshotInfo *currentPic = [pics objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
UIImage * pic = [UIImage imageWithData:currentPic.pic.imageData];
ssv.imageView.image = pic;

// even doing like below does not work
//ssv.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"fbpic.png"];
```

Should that not be enough?

Adding the UIImageView programatically works, but this should not be the solution.

Setting the image in viewdidload works, but i want the image data from the first view controller.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried `initWithNibName:nil`? If the nib and class are named the same thing the OS will load the correct nib automatically. You should avoid potential typos whenever possible.

Comment: YES - turns out the imageView was nil.... But should it not be instantiated automatically since it is connected to an outlet? Add answer Larme... Thanks both of you.

Comment: I believe this answers your question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7725624/1216394

Comment: It sure did. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When your program run at `ssv.imageView.image = pic`, the property named imageView of ssv must be `nil`. Because the root view of ssv has not been loaded. Your code of setting image runs on one run loop, while loading view of your view contoller runs on the next run loop. This is why you setting the image in `viewDidLoaded` works fine. And you should setting the properties of views of nib in the method of `viewDidLoaded`.